# how to access DB from console component application?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, oci8, symfony-2.7

I am trying to build a batch job using command console and need to connect to DB to fetch data.

I have noticed different methods from different sections to access DB. From controller `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()` is used and 
for services it is `$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()`

what is the way to connect to DB object with console component?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are writing some custom console command I believe that You can just extend it to

```
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand
```

and then just use

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')
```

to be in the right place.